# NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL throws exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, url

I´m simply trying to read a text file on a server. For testing the file is local at the moment. The code looks like:

```
        NSString *pathToLocalFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/dataVersion.txt"];
NSURL *URLToLocalFile = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:pathToLocalFile];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToLocalFile]) {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:pathToLocalFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
}

NSError *err = nil;
//NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/tags"];
    //using url also doesn't work
localFile = [[NSFileHandle alloc]fileHandleForReadingFromURL:URLToLocalFile error:&err];
localFileData = [localFile readDataToEndOfFile];
```

The Problem is located here

```
[[NSFileHandle alloc]fileHandleForReadingFromURL:URLToLocalFile error:&err];
```

It always throws the following exception:

```
**NSInvalidArgumentException**, reason: **-[NSConcreteFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.**
```

The **URLToLocalFile** object seems to be okay.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a class method, you do not need to alloc an instance.  Do this:

```
[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:URLToLocalFile error:&err];
```

Comment: damn I`m sorry for asking that